# Making "alt+shift" behave as "alt gr"/reconfiguring non standard keyboard? (Corsair SK621 Norwegian Layout)

Tags: keyboard, configuration, layout

I've recently gotten back into developing and I've installed Ubuntu in dual boot on my system(love the OS, but mostly used my computer for windows only games the past few years).

I got myself a Corsair SK621, which is a really small 60% mechanical keyboard that I love to use, however I've run into an issue getting it to work properly in Ubuntu.

The keyboard is so small that it's lacking a common key called "alt gr"(alt button to the right of the spacebar), which we use as a modifier on norwegian keyboards to access @, {[]} and other special characters. The solution for this in windows is using alt+shift as a modifier instead of "alt gr", but this does not work in Ubuntu.

[Corsair SK621 norwegian layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUPOu.jpg)

[Keyboard website](https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/peripheral/keyboards/sk621/)

Wondering if anyone knew if I could reconfigure this somehow? I've been googling around for a bit but all I can find so far is how to change the keyboard language, which doesn't really help me. I'm thinking either by making the system recognize alt+shift as the "alt gr" modifier key, or by manually mapping each character so that the system knows alt+shift+2 would give me @ etc?

Thanks for any advice! Will get back to you if I find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an update if anyone else runs into this issue with the same or a similar keyboard. 
I managed to do a workaround using Windows and another keyboard. Basically, I loaded up the CM settings for my keyboard using their windows driver, then I assigned the menu button (two buttons to the right of space) to R. Alt/Alt Gr by pressing that key on the other keyboard.
Obviously, a solution that wouldn't require Windows, another keyboard with the right key, and reassigning a key that some users might need(even though I do not) is not preferable, but it works for me.